# При переключении на Dark Mode ползунок не сохраняет позицию?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, localstorage

Подскажите начинающему неумёхе как сделать что бы при переключении темы на Dark Mode и перезагрузке страницы ползунок сохранял позицию тоже, вот код:

```js
// Dark Mode for Zero Credits
let darkMode = localStorage.getItem('darkMode');
const darkModeToggle = document.querySelector('#chk');

const enableDarkMode = () => {
  document.body.classList.add('light');
  localStorage.setItem('darkMode', 'enabled');
}
const disableDarkMode = () => {
  document.body.classList.remove('light');
  localStorage.setItem('darkMode', null);
}
if (darkMode === 'enabled') {
  enableDarkMode();
}
darkModeToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
  darkMode = localStorage.getItem('darkMode');

  if (darkMode !== 'enabled') {
    enableDarkMode();
  } else {
    disableDarkMode();
  }
});
```

```css
.theme {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 75px;
  background: #ff0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -ms-border-radius: 50px;
  -o-border-radius: 50px;
}

.checkbox {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.label {
  background-color: #111;
  border-radius: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  height: 20px;
  width: 40px;
  transform: scale(1.3);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.3);
  -o-transform: scale(1.3);
}

.label .ball {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  height: 16px;
  width: 17px;
  transform: translateX(0px);
  transition: transform 0.2s linear;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(0px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(0px);
  -o-transform: translateX(0px);
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.2s linear;
  -moz-transition: transform 0.2s linear;
  -ms-transition: transform 0.2s linear;
  -o-transition: transform 0.2s linear;
}

.checkbox:checked+.label .ball {
  transform: translateX(19px);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(19px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(19px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(19px);
  -o-transform: translateX(19px);
}

.fa-moon {
  color: #f1c40f;
}

.fa-sun {
  color: #f39c12;
}
```

```html
<div class="theme">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="chk" />
  <label class="label" for="chk">
    <ion-icon name="sunny-outline" class="fa-sun"></ion-icon>
    <ion-icon name="moon-outline" class="fa-moon"></ion-icon>
    <div class="ball"></div>
  </label>
</div>
```

Очень нужна помощь, делаю для себя.

Comment: Вставь это  if (darkMode !== 'enabled') {
    enableDarkMode();
  } else {
    disableDarkMode();
  } после let darkMode = localStorage.getItem('darkMode');

Answer (score 1):

Если добавить в JS darkModeToggle.checked=true
сюда:

```js
// Dark Mode for Zero Credits
let darkMode = localStorage.getItem('darkMode');
const darkModeToggle = document.querySelector('#chk');

const enableDarkMode = () => {
  document.body.classList.add('light');
  localStorage.setItem('darkMode', 'enabled');
}
const disableDarkMode = () => {
  document.body.classList.remove('light');
  localStorage.setItem('darkMode', null);
}
if (darkMode === 'enabled') {
   enableDarkMode();
   darkModeToggle.checked=true; // <----
}
darkModeToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
  darkMode = localStorage.getItem('darkMode');

  if (darkMode !== 'enabled') {
    enableDarkMode();
  } else {
    disableDarkMode();
  }
});
```

то при загрузке страницы JS переставит его в нужное положение!

Comment: Если это является ответом на Ваш вопрос, то тогда рекомендую отметить ответ как верный, нажав на галочку слева от текста вопроса